# IFNull in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, null, ifnull

I am new to SQL and I am trying to create a calculated field using a set of columns. However, some of those values may be NULL. If they are NULL, I don't want the calculated field to return a NULL result but instead set some arbitrary value.

Here is the calculated field

```
(ces.EXPERT_SCORE * cirm.CONSUMER_RATING) + (12.5 * scs.SIMILARITY)
```

Comment: You have the function, here's [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) -- what do you need us for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `IFNULL(tocheckwhat,withwhattoreplace)` so:

```
(IFNULL(ces.EXPERT_SCORE,5) * IFNULL(cirm.CONSUMER_RATING,5)) + (12.5 * IFNULL(scs.SIMILARITY,5))
```

should work! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE operator

```
(
 COALESCE(ces.EXPERT_SCORE, <YOUR_ARBIT_VALUE>) * 
 COALESCE(cirm.CONSUMER_RATING, <YOUR_ARBIT_VALUE>)
)
+ (12.5 * COALESCE(scs.SIMILARITY, <YOUR_ARBIT_VALUE>))
```